# "The tea is hot" - Is the verb BE transitive or not here?

Tags: verbs, transitivity

I came across a question: Whether this sentence is transitive or not..

> The tea is hot.

According to me, it should be transitive.

- The tea is **(what?)**

Please explain.

Comment: You should study the grammar terms direct object and linking verbs + complement.  Here is a first introduction into verb patterns and sentence types http://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/clause-phrase-and-sentence/verb-patterns

Comment: You should be asking whether the *verb* is transitive, not whether the *sentence* is transitive.  Transitivity isn't a property sentences can have.

Comment: @snailboat Hmm, H&P, Aarts and many others would go the other way there. They specifically say that given a choice it makes better sense to call clauses transitive, intransitive, or ditransitive - rather than verbs. CGEL p.53 "*The terms transitive, monotranstitive and ditransitive can be applied to the clause or to the head verb. Most verbs however, occur with more than one 'complementation'* " Notice the scare quotes there. Given a choice H&P always refer to the clause rather than the verb as being 'transitive' etc.

Comment: @manav +1 I respectfully disagree with Snailboat's comment there, by the way. Many grammarians say it's better to refer to the clause being transitive, not the verb, given a choice.

Comment: On that note, I distinguish sentences from clauses.

Comment: @snailboat Yes, I agree, but that's a fine point to pull the OP up on, methinks ;)

Answer (score 4):

**Short answer**

The verb *BE* is not transitive here, because *hot* is not an Object. It describes the phrase *the tea*.

---

**Explanation**

There are two ideas here. One is about how many Complements a verb takes (sometimes referred to as the valency of the verb). The other is about how many Objects a verb takes. When we talk about the transitivity of a clause, we are talking about how many Objects the verb has in that clause. Rememeber, all Objects are Complements, but Objects are a special type of Complement. There are other types of Complements that a verb can take, for example, Predicative Complements and Locative Complements.

The verb *BE* often takes Predicative Complements and Locative Complements, but it never takes Objects. In the Original Poster's example the word *hot* is a Predicative Complement. It does not talk about a new person or thing. It describes the Subject of the sentence, *the tea*. So in the Original Poster's sentence, although the verb does have a Complement, it doesn't have an Object. Because of this the verb is intransitive.

I understand why this is confusing. I agree that it is normally more useful to talk about how many Complements a verb has in a clause, not just how many Objects. This is especially true for learners of English.

Answer (score 3):

*Be*, along with a few other verbs, is a special case known as a [copula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copula_(linguistics)) - what follows it is not an object but a complement.

The main practical difference is that <strike>modifiers</strike> words that are normally modifiers can be complements.  An example:  *I am hot* - *hot* is not the object of *to be* but a complement describing *I*.

*Become* and *seem* are two other words that work like *be*.

*Appear*, *feel*, *grow*, *look*, *prove*, *remain*, *smell*, *sound*, *taste*, and *turn* are words that can be normal transitive verbs *or* take complements like *be*.

([Reference](http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/subjectcomplement.htm).)

Comment: Maybe "*words that are normally modifiers can be complements*"? (Just 'cuz by definition in normal grammar terminology modifiers can't be complements at the same time ...)

Answer (score 1):

**Hot** is not the object of the verb **is** so the sentence is intransitive. **Hot** is an adjective that describes the subject, that is, **the tea**.